# Exibindo determinados valores em Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Preciso de ajuda com o seguinte:

- Possuo uma variável que gera números inteiros aleatórios de (0 a 400).
- Em um determinado número de execuções, desejo que seja(m) exibido(s) o(s) valor(es) e a posição(ões) do(s) valor(es) menor(es) que 100.
- Possuo um código (veja abaixo) que estou trabalhando, porém ele não está agindo de maneira adequada.

Onde estou errando?

### Meu código

```
from random import randint

aleatorio = randint(0,400)
maximo = 100
for i in range(1,maximo + 1):
    if aleatorio < 100:
        print (aleatorio[i])
```

Comment: Ao todo quantas execuções queres? Não foste claro nisso

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A melhor maneira é usar um dicionário, em que cada chave pode ser a posição do valor correspondente menor que 100:

```
from random import randint

pos = {}
for idx, val in enumerate(range(400)):
    rand_num = randint(0, 400)
    if rand_num < 100:
        pos[idx] = rand_num
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](http://ideone.com/squ1FR)

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo. É exatamente o que eu preciso.

Comment: De nada @Danilo, ainda bem que resolveu. Podes trocar se quiseres, em vez de teres a posição como chave pode ser o valor. `pos[val] = idx`, ou no segundo exemplo: `{val: idx for idx, val in enumerate(rand_nums) if val < 100}`

Comment: @Danilo , peço desculpa mas cometi um enorme erro aqui... O problema do primeiro metodo (http://ideone.com/d5o068) é que ele não gerava numeros repetidos, ou seja eram gerados 400 numeros todos diferentes (0-400) na mesma, e acho que não é isso que queres. Editei para maneira certa